# Magento 2: Problem when enable developer mode

Tags: magento2, developer-mode

I have a problem when i enable developer mode:
[image]

This is my default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
  <!–referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link">
    <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="privacy-policy-link">
            <arguments>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Privacy Policy</argument> 
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode</argument>               
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

t
Thanks!

Comment: can you please run setup:di:compile. when you can get to find an error,

Answer (score 0):

The comment tag for XML format is incorrect. See the example below.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
  <!-–referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link">-->
    <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="privacy-policy-link">
            <arguments>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Privacy Policy</argument> 
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode</argument>               
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank's for your reply, now when i try to clean cache in backend , i have some errors:https://ibb.co/VtPHkfk

Comment: It looks like the template was deleted or there are no read permissions on it.